# Need help with the algebra that derive the beta 1 and beta 2 formula

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, regression

No matter how hard I tried, I can't seem to get the equation

$\sum y-(\sum x)\hat\beta_{1}=n\hat\beta_{0}$

I started by$\frac{\hat\beta_{0}}{\hat\beta_{1}}$

then I ended with

with $-\frac{\sum x}{n}$

Please give me some hint

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try calculating $\sum y-(\sum x)\hat{\beta_1}$ instead and obtain the formula fo $n\hat{\beta_0}$?

Comment: @ Luiz Cordeiro Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $Y_{i}=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$. $i=1,...,n$, so

$$ S(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i)^2,$$
derivation w.r.t. $\beta_0$ yields 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_0}S(\hat{\beta_0})= -2\sum(Y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1x_i)=0, 
$$
or equivalently
$$
\sum Y_i - n\hat{\beta}_0-\hat{\beta}_1\sum x_i=0 \, .
$$

Comment: @ A.E Thanks, but I need a little help with the partial derivatives, since it is taking $\beta_{0}$, is that n in front of it the result of the partial derivatives?

Comment: @ A.E I am new to partial derivatives, so it is the chain rule here right? you take the 2 down, and inside bracket the $\beta_{0}$ is gone, leaving the negative sign. then the -2 gets cancelled as the whole thing is equaled to 0. Then what is left is the algebraic rearrangement to the term I want?

Comment: @Tmm - Yes, you are absolutely right.